# Should I use connectOutlet in this scenario in Ember?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-router

I have a TasksList application. Each task has comments in it. I was thinking of adding comments as a Plug n Play kind of outlet.

I have a ViewerRoute which displays individual tasks:

```
App.ViewerRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function () {
        $(document).attr('title', 'Task View');
    },
   renderTemplate: function () {
        this.render('Comments', { into: "Viewer", outlet: "comment", controller: "Comment" });
    }
});
```

My viewer template has the following Outlet `{{outlet comment}}`

I also created a Comments.hbs file with a few sample markups:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="well span12">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h3>
            Followups
          </h3>
        </div>
</div>
```

but when I run the page, I get the error message that says "Cannot call method connectOutlet of undefined". I triangulated the problem to the following function inside ember

```
_lookupActiveView: function(templateName) {
    var active = this._activeViews[templateName]; //templateName is "Comment" 
    return active && active[0];
  },
```

The problem is that this function always return undefined.
Eventually when the code runs into `parentView.connectOutlet(options.outlet, view);`
it hits the error.

Am I missing something?

here is my router

```
App.Router.map(function () {

    this.resource("taskspanel", function () {
        this.resource("viewer", { path: '/viewer/:taskId' }, function () {
        });
        this.resource("new", { path: '/new' });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your named outlet is in viewer you should render into there, additionally, it appears like viewer won't be rendered since you are overriding the `renderTemplate` hook of viewer, and rendering something different.

```
 this.render();
 this.render('Comments', { into: "viewer", outlet: "comment", controller: "Comment" });
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

```
App.PostRoute = App.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('favoritePost', {   // the template to render
      into: 'posts',                // the route to render into
      outlet: 'posts',              // the name of the outlet in the route's template
      controller: 'blogPost'        // the controller to use for the template
    });
    this.render('comments', {
      into: 'favoritePost',
      outlet: 'comment',
      controller: 'blogPost'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks kingpin2k, i did that, but the error still persists. the parentView is undefined.

Comment: viewer doesn't exist in the page so that outlet won't exist (see updated answer)